# Can Access database applications be shared across desktops?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have created two applications using Visual Studio and C#.

The premise of the applications is for data entry and browsing of the data. However, I have come to the realization that these applications won't work on other devices as the data source is a local Access database. Am i able to somehow share these apps with others without giving them the Access database too? This is a major problem as my boss only wants these apps and not the database to be sent with them too. Or would I have to migrate the database to an SQL server and try to migrate the application as well?

Thank you

Comment: Not really.  In a LAN setting you could put the file on a shared folder on the network, but nothing would stop people from copying it.  You should re-write this using SQL Server or MySQL with a browser or winform front-end.  The database server (and web server for a browser app)  can live on Azure or AWS.  If the data is sensitive do think about protecting it.

Comment: Hi @Aarxn, welcome to SO. Are you looking to share the applications beyond your local network or just in-house to other computers in the same network?

Comment: Hi, I am planning to share the applications to those on the network as well as any devices they may have such as laptops. Thus that would be beyond the network yes?

Comment: Not really. If your devices are connected via WIFI, they may or may not be part of the same network. This is a crucial difference because it pertains to access to the data.

Comment: I agree with Dave and strongly advise you move away from Access. That being said, if you decide to stick with it, please read the following. It has everything you need: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ways-to-share-an-access-desktop-database-03822632-da43-4d8f-ba2a-68da245a0446

Comment: I believe everyone will be on the same network as there is a central wifi that is used but there are two.

Comment: With SQL if i convert to it, would others need any specific programs or additional items to utilize the applications?

Comment: You don't seem to have a firm grasp of the technologies involved or even your own network environment.  If your Access database is placed on a network available folder, then yes, everyone can access it.  But Access is notorious for corruption, which is why a SQL server based solution would be recommended.  This would likely require an update to your code base.  This question is way too broad to be practically answered.

Comment: You can split the solution into two Access databases, with the front end containing only your forms and linked tables. But it would be very chatty and inefficient. Far better to set up a SQL Server database.

Comment: I agree with @LarsTech. It's obvious that you are working this stuff out as you go along and there is nothing wrong with that. We all learn at some point. However, this site is intended for specific questions. Good luck figuring this out. I suggest you read and familiarize yourself more on the subject of client/server architecture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model

Comment: _With SQL if i convert to it, would others need any specific programs or additional items to utilize the applications_ No. And if you did, you'd include it as part of the application install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR:

> Can Access database applications be shared across desktops?

Yes

> Am i able to somehow share these apps with others without giving them the Access database too?

Yes

> Or would I have to migrate the database to an SQL server and try to migrate the application as well?

Not necessarily

---

It's a difficult question to answer because the question seems slightly confused

You've created an app or two that enters and shows data in an access database, and now you're asking if the app can be distributed without the Access database

Sure it can; but what then will be the purpose of the the app?

You ask if it could be switched to using sql server instead.

Sure it can, but I'm not really clear on how you think it will help because you then have to install sql server in the customer premises and give them the database. I suppose you could keep the sql server on your premises and they could connect to it, but then you could just as easily create a web service or API that sits in front of your access db and have your programs interact with the API, as a way of keeping databases off the customer premises and then stick with Access (or change it later and not affect the customers because you're providing the same api which a new db).

It's most typical, when having software that customers use and a database that you keep ownership of, to separate them with an api

As an aside, Access is terrible in a multi user configuration where two different apps are trying to use the same db file I've a file share; take any steps you can to avoid using this scenario

Stackoverflow is designed to answer particular kinds of questions and there's a real risk that this question will stray into opinion based territory and become off topic. We can't design your app for you, we can only help with implementation problems but it sounds like you need to sit back and think some more about what you're trying to solve for the problems your customers face, and see if you can get some help regarding the tech stack you should look to implement. If you desire SO to deliver these answers you'll need to ask them in a particular way, essentially having made a set of decisions yourself and be missing some facts that will drive the implementation choices - ask us for the missing facts rather than to make the implementation choices

Comment: Hi Caius, Sorry but basically the app has been created to browse and insert data without the need of the database accompanying it constantly. Rather the apps will update the database which will be stored in a certain spot if you understand what I mean. Since you have brought up the point about SQL  being installed I guess there is no point to switch over.

Comment: It sounds like you should be considering an interim layer to disconnect the app from the database so that it ultimately doesn't matter what database (or even if a database) is used

Comment: My boss wishes for their to be some sort of database stored somewhere thus the database matters when used. I am extremely new to SQL so I am wondering if I switch over my applications to SQL servers will others need any software etc? Or will they just need the application to utilize it fully?

Comment: This is the problem with bosses making design decisions like "thou shalt use a database" - it could be that something else like Azure Table Storage, or a redis cache, or a CSV file, would be more apt. Of course, I personally would argue that all these things are databases because they contain a base of data... Your question cannot be answered in its current form; it's not well developed enough to really understand what You're asking, what you're aiming to create or what problem you're trying to solve. At the moment I can really only say "yes. Or no. Maybe. It depends"

Comment: Typically when we develop an application that requires a back end database server X to operate then Yes that database software needs to be installed somewhere and licensed by someone

Comment: _if I switch over my applications to SQL servers will others need any software_ the clients (users) certainly won't need anything special as SQL Server drivers come installed by default in windows. You'll need a SQL Server running somewhere, and that is software you'll need.

Comment: They'll also need a reasonably reliable internet connection that will permit them access to whatever you create that accesses your server. If they are on a fairly-to-well-locked-down network direct access to an sql server on port 1433 might not work out. Access to a web service on port 80/443 is much more likely to work and it hides the implementation detail that you use SQL server/means you don't have to provide direct access to your sql server; you're instead providing access to servers that suffer attack attempts far more regularly (and may be better hardened against them).

Comment: Few people ever make their sql server directly accessible to their customers

Answer (score 0):

If all the clients apps are on the same network and can see a central server, then there's no reason you can't use the Access database in the same way you would a SQL Server database, i.e. by placing it somewhere where it can be accessed by all copies of your application.  Access isn't the last word in database features or security, but it's perfectly workable.

We normally create a mapped drive on the client PCs to a location on the server, so that everyone can use the same connection string for the database, e.g. T:\yourdatabase.mdb.

If the clients aren't on the same network and you can't use a VPN to connect them then to single network then things will become a lot more difficult, and moving to SQL Server will probably be a lot simpler.

Essentially, if this is an in-house system where the data isn't too sensitive and all the users are members of staff say, then a central Access database can work fine.  If this is an app that's being used by people outside your organisation then SQL is a better choice if you want your app to talk directly to the database.

Alternatively you could write an API that you host on a web server, then your client apps can talk to the API and your API can talk to the Access database.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I just have a question concerning storing the file where it can be accessed by everyone. When I create the connection to the database aren't they only local connections (C:\...) Thus, others won't have the same file location if you understand what I mean. SQL can be connected to online/through a server thus it wouldn't be needed to be stored in a specific location. Or am I completely wrong.

Comment: @Aarxn We normally create a mapped drive on the client PCs to a location on the server, so that everyone can use the same connection string for the database, e.g. T:\yourdatabase.mdb

Comment: You just store it in a shared location, like a shared drive. If you can't do that, please edit your question and clarify further.

Comment: @tomRedox note though that there is no requirement for identical connection strings. Notwithstanding that multiple connections to an access database will likely eventually result in deadlock, the same file can be accessed by different share paths etc without a problem (there will be problems but it won't be because one machine is hitting c:\temp\my.mdb and the other is using \\piggy\shares\temp\my.mdb)